# Inkscape extremely slow on new, powerful computer

Tags: windows-10, performance, inkscape

Last week I bought an ASUS ultrabook laptop:

- i7 6500U processor;
- 256 GB SSD hard drive;
- 8GB RAM memory;
- Intel HD Graphics 5500 video card.

I was told this laptop should be extraordinary fast. However, working in Inkscape on Windows 10, it is extremely slow.

Is it the hardware, or might there be some other reason for Inkscape being this slow?

Answer (score 9):

Your laptop is fine. It is actually more than well-equipped to handle working with vector graphics.

The issue here is with Inkscape, itself, which renders to screen quite slowly, due to a complete lack of GPU acceleration. This is especially true when working with blur and filters.

There are a few tricks for minimizing the performance impact of more complex images in Inkscape. They involve working in multiple layers, for more complex projects, working in view modes (i.e., to toggle viewing with and without filters), and disabling the view of layers not being actively worked on.

Really, this needs to be fixed in Inkscape, which can be become unbearably slow, even when working on modest projects.

Comment: I know this is a few months old, but I've always wondered the same thing.  I notice on the [roadmap](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Roadmap) that the next release (v0.93, probably complete in a year or two) should include some startup performance improvements (hooray!), and some time after v1.5 they estimate they may finally have GPU acceleration.  At the current release rate, I calculate that v1.5 should be finished, polished and ready for public release in about 120 years from now, give or take.  I'm really looking forward to it, it's going to be a great release.

Comment: Agree with the answer and the comment. Even for CPU rendering the program performs terrible and fixing this is at least a 5 man year problem, so expect it to be rever resolved unless they put it on MIT license and let other people implement and make money with it.

Answer (score 3):

After two years working with incredibly slow inkskape on windows 10 I found the reason on my computer. I found an old Inkscape-0.48 folder under C:\Program Files. It included an old python installation. Since I removed that old Inkscape folder with admin rigths, the currently installed inkscape runs again with normal speed.

Answer (score 1):

Since 0.91 release the Inkscape is very slow. Latest 1.0beta1 is faster but is slow when panning.
If you don't need the new extra features, install the very fast 0.48.5 release.

Comment: I can confirm that this bug existed on 0.92 and downgrading to 0.48.5 will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An Ultrabook is thin and light. It is not necessarily ultrafast. The i7 6500**U** is an ultrabook-specific CPU, so it won't be as fast as a laptop or desktop CPU. Also, the Intel HD graphics are fine for general computer use, but they're not super powerful for gaming or applications that can make use of GPU features like CUDA cores.

That said, an ultrabook like yours should still perform OK with Inkscape. You may find that there are some delays in starting Inkscape, and that is somewhat normal while the software loads (particularly if you're using the portable apps version).

You might want to make sure you've got all of the Windows 10 updates and all of the driver updates for your system. You might also find that Inkscape just isn't fully supporting Windows 10 yet.

Comment: Unlike Blender which has NVIDIA CUDA support in the latest version, Inkscape does not currently use GPU hardware acceleration. According to [Inkscape Roadmap](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Roadmap) Inkscape 1.5 ~ Stabilization, GPU hardware acceleration is a feature on the Inkscape roadmap for future development.

Comment: I have a desktop machine, I7 3.3GHz, 8GB Ram, with 256Gb kingston SSD, and an ATI Radeon 7700 HD card with 1Gb memory with Win10 64bit, and when I open inkscape, it takes about 15 sec to open inkscape with a blank document. Threads pushed up to max, no recent documents list, so it should be the problem of the code of inkscape.

Comment: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html @ThunderFrame, the "U" stands for Ultra-low power, meaning that it can be cooled easily. It's not Ultrabook-specific; it means it's a nerfed mobile version of the same processor.