# Inkscape installation slow at constant 12+% CPU

Tags: windows-10, performance, inkscape

I saw that a new version of Inkscape is available and I wanted to update to the latest version. The installation routine uninstalled the old version, then started the installation of the new version (0.92.4).

However, the installation is really slow: it is now 10:37 local time and with Process Explorer, I can see that the installation was started at 09:44 local time, i.e. it is running for more than 50 minutes now, with very little progress.

[image: Process Explorer Screenshot]

From the labels I can see it still does something. The line

> Search in: [...]\numpy\distutils

sometimes changes.

[image: Screenshot]

Another thing I notice is that the kernel time is overly high:

[image: Kernel usage]

How do I make the installation as fast as it used to be (less than 5 minutes, I'd say)?

I'm using the Inkscape 0.92.4 Windows 64 Bit Exe Installer. My OS is Windows 10.

I've tried:

- killing the Setup and restarting.

This is not a duplicate of [Inkscape extremely slow on new powerful computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1024629/inkscape-extremely-slow-on-new-powerful-computer), since that question discusses an already installed version of Inkscape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread causing 12% CPU usage often displays

```
ntoskrnl.exe!KiSwapContext+0x76
ntoskrnl.exe!KiSwapThread+0x2c6
ntoskrnl.exe!KiCommitThreadWait+0x13b
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x1ff
ntoskrnl.exe!KiSchedulerApc+0x30a
ntoskrnl.exe!KiDeliverApc+0x27b
ntoskrnl.exe!KiCheckForKernelApcDelivery+0x27
ntoskrnl.exe!NtReadFile+0x79e
ntoskrnl.exe!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
wow64cpu.dll!CpupSyscallStub+0xc
wow64cpu.dll!ReadWriteFileFault+0x31
wow64cpu.dll!BTCpuSimulate+0x9
wow64.dll!RunCpuSimulation+0xa
wow64.dll!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x120
ntdll.dll!_LdrpInitialize+0x109
ntdll.dll!LdrpInitialize+0x3b
ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
```

It looks like Inkscape Setup is trying to read files.

It looks like something went wrong with the deinstallation of the old version.
The following helped:

- kill the running Inkscape setup
- delete the whole folder `%ProgramFiles%\Inkscape`
- run Inkscape setup again